# Использование методов async снизу до самого верха

Tags: c#

Допустим в недрах программы, есть метод:

```
public static string WriteSomeMethod(string Somedata){
    //Бурная долгая деятельность
    return SomeData2; //Имитация возвращения данных
}
```

При этом мы хотим, что бы наша программа не вешалась при вызове этого метода, поэтому пишем еще один:

```
public static async Task<string> WriteSome(string Somedata){
    return await Task.Run(()=> WriteSomeMethod(Somedata));
}
```

Если мы где-то в другом коде попытаемся вызвать `var tmpdata = WriteSome("123");` то увидим, что var - на самом деле не `string`, а `Task<string>`. Что бы нам получить string нужно сделать так: `var tmpdata = await WriteSome("123");`, и сделать этот метод асинхронным.

Сделав его асинхронным, нужно будет сделать результат его работы Task'ом, =>
необходимо повторить это вплоть до момента, когда мы упремся в обработчик события и сделаем его асинхронным. Как этого избежать, и просто вернуть из WriteSome сразу строку?

P.S. иногда будет не строка а класс, с тонной переменных.

Comment: `return Task.Run(() => WriteSomeMethod(Somedata)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: @Bulson `мы хотим, что бы наша программа не вешалась при вызове этого метода`

Comment: Вы хотите сделать обработчик синхронным и при этом, чтобы выполнение метода не блокировало UI? А в чем проблема использовать асинхронный обработчик? Он кстати может быть и `async void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите пользоваться асинхронностью и иметь максимум пользы от этого, то да, с самого низа и до самого верха, пока вызывающий код интересуют результаты работы вызываемого кода, вам придется везде вверх по стеку менять сигнатуры методов и делать методы асинхронными. Мало того, вот эта конструкция

```
public static async Task<string> WriteSome(string Somedata){
    return await Task.Run(()=> WriteSomeMethod(Somedata));
}
```

Смысла не имеет, так как это лишнее ожидание, у вас внутри метода только 1 таск, результаты которого вы только пробросить наверх хотите? Делайте так, получите меньше сгенерированных стейт машин в результате:

```
public static Task<string> WriteSomeAsync(string Somedata){
    return Task.Run(()=> WriteSomeMethod(Somedata));
}
```

Comment: В комментарии вы верно заметили. `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - действительно блокирующий вызов. Я вспомнил о нем потому, что  в best practices такой вызов был назван более правильным нежели `Wait()` в случае, если необходимо вызвать синхронно асинх.метод.